# [R]: Flag overlapping time periods

Tags: r

Below dataframe shows promotion calendar for products i.e. what week promotion starts, which products are promoted, and how long the promotion is.

I need a function that will create a flag (by PromoID and StartWk) indicating if a Product-WeekNum combination is duplicated where WeekNum is (StartWk) to (StartWk + Duration). So WeekNum for first row is Week 5 and 6 (and so on). Basically, if any Product-WeekNum combination is duplicated then corresponding PromoID-StartWk combination gets flagged. WeekNum is shown as R comments.

If no such instances, then function should output an empty dataframe with output fields.

Highly desirable - An empty dataframe passed to the function should produce an empty dataframe with output fields.

If it helps, any given PromoID will always have the same set of Products and same Duration at all instances.

```
df <- structure(list(PromoID = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "C", 
"C", "D", "A", "A", "E", "E"), Product = c("Flavored", "Original", 
"Flavored", "Original", "Flavored", "Original", "Flavored", "Original", 
"Flavored", "Flavored", "Original", "Energy", "Energy"), StartWk = c(5L, 
5L, 21L, 21L, 30L, 30L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 49L, 49L), Duration = c(2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L)), .Names = c("PromoID", 
"Product", "StartWk", "Duration"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-13L))

   PromoID  Product StartWk Duration
1        A Flavored       5        2 # WeekNum 5, 6
2        A Original       5        2 # WeekNum 5, 6
3        A Flavored      21        2 # WeekNum 21, 22
4        A Original      21        2 # WeekNum 21, 22
5        B Flavored      30        3 # WeekNum 30, 31, 32
6        B Original      30        3 # WeekNum 30, 31, 32
7        C Flavored       6        1 # WeekNum 6
8        C Original       6        1 # WeekNum 6
9        D Flavored       5        2 # WeekNum 5, 6
10       A Flavored       5        2 # WeekNum 5, 6
11       A Original       5        2 # WeekNum 5, 6
12       E   Energy      49        1 # WeekNum 49
13       E   Energy      49        1 # WeekNum 49
```

Expected Output -

```
  PromoID StartWk Flag
1       A       5    1
2       C       6    1
3       D       5    1
4       E      49    1
```

Comment: Sorry I do not understand: if there is a repetition in combination of PromoID and StartWk, do you want a flag? How it is implied Duration? Product is useless?

Comment: @s_t Yes, I want a flag for that. Your scenario will automatically result in duplicated Product-WeekNum since PromoID will always have the same set of Products in all instances. Added this detail to the question.

Comment: Why in your result `2       A      21    1` is not appearing (with colnames as yout result)?

Comment: PromoID A is for weeks 21 to 22 and does not overlap with any other Product-WeekNum combination. Added WeekNum as r comments in post.

Comment: Sorry for the questions, but `4       E      49    1` is overlapping with?

Comment: `4 E 49 1` is overlapping with itself. I included it as a special case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df %>%
  # Make row for each week of each promotion
  tidyr::uncount(weights = Duration, .id = "wk_no") %>%
  # Show what week is represented by each row
  mutate(CurWk = StartWk + wk_no - 1) %>%
  # How many Promos are there for each product each week?
  add_count(Product, CurWk) %>%
  # Only include overlapping promos
  filter(n > 1) %>%

  # To shape into requested output form, only show one row per overlap
  group_by(PromoID, StartWk) %>%
  summarize(Flag = 1)
```

Output

```
# A tibble: 4 x 3
# Groups:   PromoID [?]
  PromoID StartWk  Flag
  <chr>     <int> <dbl>
1 A             5     1
2 C             6     1
3 D             5     1
4 E            49     1
```

Comment: This is great! However the `uncount(df, weights = Duration, .id = "wk_no") %>% mutate(CurWk = StartWk + wk_no - 1)` fails for empty dataframe as column `wk_no` does not get created. Is there an elegant way around this without using `if else`?

Comment: Here's an empty dataframe for your reference - 
`df_empty <- data.frame(PromoID = character(), ProductLow = character(), StartWk = integer(), Duration = integer(), stringsAsFactors = F)`

Comment: Not exactly elegant, but you could add `add_row(PromoID = "", Product = "", Duration = 0) %>%` as the first row after `df %>%`. This won't impact the normal data, but will allow the empty data set (if you use `Product` instead of `ProductLow`) to process without error and produce an empty data frame.

Comment: This is elegant enough! Thanks!